# PB using JdbcBatchItemWriter with CompositeItemWriter in JAVA code- Spring-Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have extended the batch service code provided by Official Spring-Batch site -  [Batch Processing Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/) and modified the ItemWriter to generate the CSV and to write to the database.

I have used CompositeItemWriter to write in both CSV and Database.
However the JdbcBatchItemWriter is not working correctly with CompositeItemWriter. The code is shown below.

```
    @Bean
public ItemWriter<Person> writer(DataSource dataSource) {
CompositeItemWriter<Person> cWriter = new CompositeItemWriter<Person>();   

// For DataBase 
JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person>();
    writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Person>());
    writer.setSql("INSERT INTO people (first_name, last_name) VALUES (:firstName, :lastName)");
    writer.setDataSource(dataSource);

// For CSV
FlatFileItemWriter<Person> csvWriter = new FlatFileItemWriter<Person>();
csvWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource(new File("./csv/new-data.csv")));
csvWriter.setShouldDeleteIfExists(true);
DelimitedLineAggregator<Person> lineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<Person>();
lineAggregator.setDelimiter(","); 

BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Person> fieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Person>();
String[] names = {"firstName", "lastName"};
fieldExtractor.setNames(names);
lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(fieldExtractor);
csvWriter.setLineAggregator(lineAggregator);

List<ItemWriter<? super Person>> mWriter = new ArrayList<ItemWriter<? super Person>>();
mWriter.add(writer); // **Comment this line and the code works fine**
mWriter.add(csvWriter);
cWriter.setDelegates(mWriter);
    return cWriter;
}
```

Comment this line - mWriter.add(writer); to run the code. This shows that CompositeItemWriter is working good with FlatFileitemWriter, but not with JdbcBatchItemWriter. The error I am getting is -

```
or.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammerException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar 
[insert into people(first_name, last_name) VALUES (:firstName, :lastName)]

Caused by: Syntax error in SQl statement "insert into people((first_name, last_name) VALUES (:[*]firstName, :lastName)"; expected"), DEFAULT, NOT, EXISTS, INTERSECTS, SELECT, FROM"; SQL Statement:
```

How can I resolve JdbcBatchItemWriter to work correctly with CompositeItemWriter ?

Comment: Can you check your SQL, I see here double brackets... insert into person((first_name

Comment: I think you are checking the error (It's a typo). Please see the code instead which is correct.

Comment: other than a double ) why 'insert into **person**' and not 'insert into **people**'?

Comment: It's a typo corrected it. But the problem is not with query, If I return writer from above code database insertion is working correctly, which means the above query is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its the problem with jdbc auto config which was not running in case of multiple itemWriters. Pls add the last line in same sequence :-

```
JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person>();
writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Person>());
writer.setSql("INSERT INTO people (first_name, last_name) VALUES (:firstName, :lastName)");
writer.setDataSource(dataSource);

writer.afterPropertiesSet();
```

Comment: Not working. Getting the same exception. However if I comment the line mWriter.add(writer); and return CompositeItemWriter it works fine.Problem is when I add JDBCBatchItemWriter in CompositeItemWriter.

Comment: I just imported the Spring project from link you provided & changed the ItemWriter to what you using and getting following error which is different from what you saying. Pls verify:-                                    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcBatchItemWriter.java:189)
 at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcBatchItemWriter.java:185)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:644)

Comment: Thanks for checking Avis. I am not sure what happened because I am also getting the same exception now !!
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcBatchItemWriter.java:189)
 at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcBatchItemWriter.java:185)