# Spring Batch multiple insert for a one read

Tags: java, spring-batch

I've a Spring Batch process that read Report objects from a CSV and insert Analytic objects into a MySQL DB correctly, but the logical has changed for a more than one Analytics insert for each Report readed.

I'm new in Spring Batch and the actually process was very difficult for me, and I don't know how to do this change.

I haven't XML configuration, all is with annotations. Report and Analytics classes have a getter and a setter for two fields, adId and value. The new logic has seven values for an adId and I need to insert seven rows into table.

I hide, delete or supress some code that not contribute for the question.

Here is my BatchConfiguration.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessingpublic
class BatchConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private transient JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private transient StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private transient DataSource dataSource;

    public FlatFileItemReader<Report> reader() {
        // The reader from the CSV works fine.
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Analytic> writer() {
        final JdbcBatchItemWriter<Analytic> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<Analytic>();
        writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Analytic>());
        writer.setSql("INSERT INTO TABLE (ad_id, value) VALUES (:adId, :value)");
        writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public AnalyticItemProcessor processor() {
        return new AnalyticItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<Report, Analytic> chunk(10000).reader(reader()).processor(processor()).writer(writer()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job process() {
        final JobBuilder jobBuilder = jobBuilderFactory.get("process");

        return jobBuilder.start(step()).build();
    }
}
```

Then the AnalyticItemProcessor.java

```
public class AnalyticItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Report, Analytic> {
    @Override
    public Analytic process(final Report report) {
        // Creates a new Analytic call BeanUtils.copyProperties(report, analytic) and returns analytic.
    }
}
```

And the Process:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Process {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Process.class, args);
    }
}
```

How can I do this change? Maybe with ItemPreparedStatementSetter or ItemSqlParameterSourceProvider? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can use the `CompositeItemWriter` to wrap multiple `JdbcBatchItemWriter` instances (one per insert you need to accomplish).  That would allow you to insert multiple rows per item.  Otherwise, you'd need to write your own `ItemWriter` implementation.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Minella, with the ItemWriter implementation was OK. Very important include "writer.afterPropertiesSet();" like says Avis in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656581/pb-using-jdbcbatchitemwriter-with-compositeitemwriter-in-java-code-spring-batch

Comment: If you configure each of the delegates as a bean, you don't need to.  The container will do it for you.